# Z3 nuZ: Support for nonlinear optimization problems

Tags: optimization, z3

In an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211490/does-z3-have-support-for-optimization-problems) question, Leonardo posts a link to "Exact nonlinear optimization on demand". This sounds like nonlinear optimization will be (or is?) supported by vZ. In the paper "νZ - An Optimizing SMT Solver", the abstract says:

> νZ
>   provides a portfolio of approaches for solving
>   linear  optimization  problems  over  SMT  formulas,  MaxSMT,  and  their
>   combinations.

This again sounds like nonlinear optimizations are out of scope at the moment.

I played around with this smt2 code:

```
(set-option :pp.decimal true)
(set-option :produce-models true)

(declare-fun x () Real)
(declare-fun y () Real)

(assert (= y (+ 1 (^ (- x 1) 2.0))))
(assert (and (<= (- 3.0) x) (< x 3.0)))
(assert (and (<= (- 3.0) y) (< y 3.0)))
(minimize y)

(check-sat)
(get-value (x y))
(exit)
```

As an answer I get this response:

```
unknown
(objectives
 (y  ((* (- 1) oo) oo))
)
((x 0.0)
 (y 2.0))
```

So I guess, that nonlinear functions are indeed not supported by vZ.

Are there plans in doing so?